# Text before php header not giving errors

Tags: php, header

I'm new to development and I'm trying to learn php.

Why is it that when I use the code below, the redirection, (through the header syntax), is still taking place even though content has been output before it ?

```
<html>
    <body>
    <p>My Page</p>
    </body>
</html>

<?php

    $redirect_page = 'http://localhost';
    $redirect = true;
    echo "Some Text";
    if($redirect==true){
        header('Location: '.$redirect_page);    
    }
?>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have output buffering on?

Comment: @JohnConde He is probably on localhost and it is on by default :)

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting for all levels?

Comment: Try this: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`

Comment: error_reporting is set to E_ALL in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

HTTP requires response headers to arrive strictly before the body content, like so:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Powered-By: PHP/7.0.0-20150527
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>
```

For PHP to comply with that requirement, **PHP must send *all* accumulated headers at the instant it's ready to send *any* body content**.  The answer to your question hinges on the definition of when PHP is "ready to send".

To figure that out, look at your `output_buffering` setting:

```
var_dump(ini_get('output_buffering'));
```

On my machine with default settings, that returns `4096`, which [according to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) means that PHP will be "ready to send" when 4096 body bytes have been accumulated.

To get the page to behave as you expect (ie, *not* sending the headers), you need to output enough bytes to exceed the setting of `output_buffering`.  You can either do that by reducing the output buffering setting or by emitting more body text, eg:

`echo str_repeat('<div/>', 4096);`

See also this [SO primer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/2908724).